# jq fails to parse when one of the values contains a backslash

Tags: jq

I have a json output, representing a linux command in one of it's values:

```
... ,"proc.cmdline":"sh -c pgrep -fl \"unicorn.* worker\[.*?\]\"", ...
```

In some cases, the command contains a backslash, so the outputing json will contain a backslash too.

I need to parse the output with jq, but it fails with an error:

```
parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 373
```

It refers to this: `\[`

However, this is a part of the command, so it is expected to be there.

If a manually edit the line, converting `\[` to `\\[`, then it passes. However the resulting output contains both backslashes:

```
...
"proc.cmdline": "sh -c pgrep -fl \"unicorn.* worker\\[.*?\\]\"",
...
```

Now, I can't be there to manually edit every time. This output is produced automatically by another software, and I need to parse it with jq every time it comes in.

Also, even if I was able to edit every `\[` to `\\[`, (like by using something like `sed`) the output becomes a lie, the second `\` is fake.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

---

EDIT: here is the full json for reference (received raw by the output of the program I'm using (falco)):

```
{"priority":"Debug","rule":"Run shell untrusted","time":"2019-05-15T07:32:36.597411997Z", "output_fields": {"evt.time":1557905556597411997,"proc.aname[2]":"gitlab-mon","proc.aname[3]":"runsv","proc.aname[4]":"runsvdir","proc.aname[5]":"wrapper","proc.aname[6]":"docker-containe","proc.aname[7]":"docker-containe","proc.cmdline":"sh -c pgrep -fl \"unicorn.* worker\[.*?\]\"","proc.name":"sh","proc.pcmdline":"reactor.rb:249                                                                       ","proc.pname":"reactor.rb:249","user.name":null}}
```

Comment: Why would you need to escape the `[` under `".."` in the first-place? You don't need to do. See `echo '{
    "proc.cmdline":"sh -c pgrep -fl \"unicorn.* worker[.*?]\""
}' |  jq '."proc.cmdline"'` works just fine

Comment: @Inian, I did not escape it. The value of `proc.cmdline` is representing the command executed, with all arguments *as is*. The `\[` is not an attempt to escape the `[`, it is just part of the command as it was executed. I'm not writing those commands, I'm just handling the output of the process auditing them.

Comment: @oguzismail I'm getting this error in 1.6 as well. I'll edit my question with the full json for you to try

Answer (score 2):

JSON standard is quite explicit about which characters have to be escaped, and `[` is not one of them (though reverse solidus - `\` is). So it's your script / software generating JSON violates the JSON standard - you can validate it on any of well-known online JSON validators, e.g., like this one: https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/ - it will produce the error too.

If you cannot enhance/fix your script generating that JSON, then you'd need to ensure you double quote those non-compliant quotations before passing to JSON processor: e.g.

```
... | sed -E 's/\\([][])/\\\\\1/g' | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fix whatever is generating that "json" string. Use something that produces compliant json.

If that's not an option for you, then you will have to modify it so that it is valid json. Fortunately `jq` can handle that. Read it in raw, fix the string then parse it.

Assuming we just need to fix the `\[` and `\]` sequence:

```
$ ... | jq -R 'gsub("\\\\(?<c>[[\\]])"; "\\\\\(.c)") | fromjson | "your filter"'
```

Remember, `"sh -c pgrep -fl \"unicorn.* worker\\[.*?\\]\""` is a string with escapes... it represents the value:

```
sh -c pgrep -fl "unicorn.* worker\[.*?\]"
```

So it's absolutely correct to have "both backslashes."